# Nested For Loops and Column Renaming

Tags: r

How do I rename columns based on conditions in other columns in nested for loops?

I'm trying to do this in R:
If column named `A1` is not empty and columns `A2` through `Ak` (`k` is some number) are empty, then rename columns `B2...Bk` to `B1_1...B1_k`

A simplified sample of my data:

```
A1  B1  A2  B2  A3  B3  A4  B4

1    1      2       3       4

a    b      d       c   e   f
```

The basic concept is that if `Aj` is empty, then the corresponding `B` entry "belongs" to the previous column index `A[j-1]` and so it needs to be renamed.

I know where the positions of those columns are so when I tried to do it I used their position in the dataframe. The code below is what I'm thinking of doing but I don't know very much R syntax and couldn't get anything to work:

```
for (k in 1:20){
for (j in 1:600){
for (i in 0:90) {

  if (df[j,2*i]!="" && df[j,2*i+2*k]=="") {B[i+1_[i+1]]=df[j,1+2*i+2*k]}

}}}
```

I've looked at somewhat similar posts on stackoverflow but I'm a novice and didn't understand most of it.

Comment: can you provide the relevant question?

Comment: @xlembouras I added a general question to the top. Sorry if it isn't clear throughout my post to what I'm asking.

Comment: To what purpose?  Column names are **not** what you want to be testing for contents of said columns.  Forget about the `for` construction -- there are easier ways -- but tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: first try to write 2*i instead of 2i :-p

Comment: @Carl Witthoft  Each A column with something in it is the name of a well and the B columns are the characteristics of those wells. Some of the wells have multiple characteristics but when I was stripping this data from pdfs it registered the extra characteristics as belonging to a new well(which didn't exist so its empty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note `B1_1...B1_k` needs to be one element shorter e.g. `B1_1..B1_k-1`

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    A1=c(1, "a"),
    B1=c(1, "b"),
    A2=c("", ""),
    B2=c(2, "d"),
    A3=c("", ""),
    B3=c(3, "c"),
    A4=c("", "e"),
    B4=c(4, "f"))
### get columns which are Empty 
Es <- colnames(df1)[sapply(1:ncol(df1), function(x) all((df1[x])=="") )]
### find largest no. following A in these empties
k1 <- max(as.integer(gsub("A", "", Es)))
### replace colums B2..Bk with B1_1...Bk-1
colnames(df1)[grepl("B", colnames(df1))][2:k1] <- paste0("B1_",seq(k1)[-k1])
> df1
  A1 B1 A2 B1_1 A3 B1_2 A4 B4
1  1  1       2       3     4
2  a  b       d       c  e  f
```

**Edit** Like so?

```
### get columns with at least one empty cell
### same as above but replace `all` with `any`
Es <- colnames(df1)[sapply(1:ncol(df1), function(x) any((df1[x])=="") )]
### find largest no. following A in these empties
k1 <- max(as.integer(gsub("A", "", Es)))
### new data frame with columns B2...Bk
df2 <- df1[grepl("B", colnames(df1))][2:k1]
### rename
colnames(df2) <- paste0("B1_",seq(k1)[-k1])
> (cbind(df1, df2))
  A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3 A4 B4 B1_1 B1_2 B1_3
1  1  1     2     3     4    2    3    4
2  a  b     d     c  e  f    d    c    f
```

This approach of generating a new `data.frame` then `cbind`ing isn't v. memory efficient, but this shouldn't matter much for small sizes and I think it makes the code easier to read.

Here's a `data.table` approach which avoids in-memory duplication, so useful for larger sets:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
### get k1 as above
### get columns B2...Bk
Bs <- paste0("B", seq(k1)[-1])
### add/assign duplicated columns with new column names using :=
> (dt1[, paste0("B1_",seq(k1)[-k1]) := dt1[, Bs, with=FALSE] ])
   A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3 A4 B4 B1_1 B1_2 B1_3
1:  1  1     2     3     4    2    3    4
2:  a  b     d     c  e  f    d    c    f
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to create a new column for the B1_1 and leave the old B_2? And then would it be possible to consider the emptiness in each row? Meaning B4 would be B1_3.